# NSOperation Queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished causes NSOperation instance deinit late

Tags: swift, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

Our app currently using `NSOperation` (`Operation` in Swift) to manage serials of network request and data parsing.
Some code are required to be executed after like all 5 operations in a queue are finished, which typically implemented with GCD group.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    (0...5).forEach(){
        self.queue.addOperation(CustomOperation(value: $0))
    }
    self.queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
    print("All Tasks Done")
}
```

The issue is `NSOperation` instance not `deinit` until all 5 operations done, which is causing memory release late than it supposed to.
If `queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` is removed, the instance will be `deinit` immediately.

We've added autorelease pool to avoid it. But is it possible to make `NSOperation` instance `deinit` immediately when use `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`?

prints with `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`

```
Begin Task 5
Begin Task 4
Begin Task 3
Begin Task 2
Begin Task 1
Begin Task 0
Finish Task 0
Finish Task 1
Finish Task 2
Finish Task 3
Finish Task 4
Finish Task 5
deinit 0
deinit 1
deinit 2
deinit 3
deinit 4
deinit 5
All Tasks Done
```

prints without `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`

```
All Tasks Done
Begin Task 0
Begin Task 1
Begin Task 4
Begin Task 3
Begin Task 5
Finish Task 0
Begin Task 2
deinit 0
Finish Task 1
deinit 1
Finish Task 2
deinit 2
Finish Task 3
deinit 3
Finish Task 4
deinit 4
Finish Task 5
deinit 5
```

The custom operation.

```
class CustomOperation: Operation {
    
    public enum State {
        case ready
        case running
        case finished
    }

    private var state: State = .ready
    
    override var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }
    
    override open var isExecuting: Bool { state == .running }

    override open var isFinished: Bool { state == .finished }

    var value: Int = 0
    
    init(value: Int) {
        super.init()
        
        self.value = value
    }
    
    override func main() {
        print("Begin Task \(value)")
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(value)) {
            print("Finish Task \(self.value)")
            self.finish()
        }
    }
    
    func finish() {
        willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        state = .finished
        didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but this is not thread-safe. As [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/) say, “If you implement custom methods in your subclass, such as custom data accessors, you must also make sure those methods are thread-safe.” Also, note that you never set your `state` to `.running` (which I usually do in `start` but you could do it in `main`, too). Also, we generally have a state for `cancelled`, too. But none of this is related to the question at hand, but just a friendly observation.

Comment: FWIW, rather than `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` (which blocks one of the finite number of worker threads), we would use either a completion operation (w dependencies) or barrier operation. They both suffer from the same issue as here, but they’re better than `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` (no blocked threads, no need to dispatch this to global queue, etc.). In answer to your question, we would just have the `finish` function release any objects from memory. The operation, itself, takes up very little memory, so decouple your memory consumption from when operations are deallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't know about that behavior but I don't think that you can do something here.
If you are concerned about operation order you can set the queue to have a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1 so that you can keep order.
If you are concerned about memory and you have some huge data you can get rid of that in the `finish()` method or use a `completionBlock` to pass it around.
There also the option to use KVO on the `OperationQueue` properties, most of its properties are KVO and KVC compliant and you can set observation on some of them to trigger a callback.
If you are deploying target >=13 you can use Combine as already written by vadian.

Comment: Good answer about simply cleaning up the data in `finish`. This is the correct answer. The digression about sacrificing concurrency if you care about the order is not correct: Collate the responses to get them in the right order, but do not sacrifice performance unnecessarily like that.

Answer (score 1):

A better way than *waiting* is for example observing the operation count

```
import Combine

DispatchQueue.global().async {
     (0...5).forEach {
         queue.addOperation(CustomOperation(value: $0))
     }
 }

var store : AnyCancellable?

store = queue.publisher(for: \.operationCount)
    .sink { value in
        if value == 0 { print("All Tasks Done")}
    }
```

My suggestion uses Combine, it's also possible with traditional KVO

Comment: I’d suggest that if you’re going to use Combine, then there’s no need for the operations at all. It has its own patterns for asynchronous methods, controlling degree of concurrency. If you make the leap to Combine, I’d suggest excising the operations entirely.